# Incorrect URL for AVURLAsset

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am preparing the URL for one method of `AVURLAsset`:

`+ (AVURLAsset *)URLAssetWithURL:(NSURL *)URL options:(NSDictionary *)options`

My URL belongs to a file which is written to the document path of my app. The result of `NSLog` the path is:

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E0E64E72-9A47-4E62-B9C6-818AB8BF3F4C/Documents/audio.wav

After got the `NSString *path`, I tried to convert NSString to NSURL by `[NSURL URLWithString:path]` and `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]`, but both of them are incorrect for `URLAssetWithURL`.

Error of `URLWithString` is:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could
>   not be completed" UserInfo=0x170269f80 {NSUnderlyingError=0x17405f440
>   "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12780.)",
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12780),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

And `fileURLWithPath` crashed the app.

I know `url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fileURL withExtension:@"wav"]` will fit the situation. But I want to get the url of a local file to fit `URLAssetWithURL` as well. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: The `fileURLWithPath` is the right way to convert path to a file URL. You say it "crashed the app". What precisely happened? Did the file URL look OK? Did you confirm that the file was actually found at that location?

Comment: @Rob When it crashed, Xcode only displayed a message: terminate called throwing an exception (lldb). And the crash happened before the file URL can be log in console (same code, except replacing URLWithString with fileURLWithPath). If using URLWithString, the file URL was "file:///var/mobile/Containers/.../Documents/audio.wav".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way of getting a file from the documents should work:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths.firstObject stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file"] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"wav"];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
}
```